# How to overwrite next rows using UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, self-join

I have this **MYSQL** table (simplified version) with some erased ids:

```
+-----+-------+---------+
| id  | name  | country |
+-----+-------+---------+
| 1   | John  | England |
| 5   | Emily |   USA   |
| 9   |  Joe  |   USA   |
| 11  |Michael|   USA   |
| 13  | Liam  |   USA   |
+-----+-------+---------+
```

How do I overwrite each row from "John" using php? (last name "Liam" gets kicked out)

I want it to look like this:

```
+-----+-------+---------+
| id  | name  | country |
+-----+-------+---------+
| 1   | John  | England |
| 5   | John  |   USA   |
| 9   | Emily |   USA   |
| 11  |  Joe  |   USA   |
| 13  |Michael|   USA   |
+-----+-------+---------+
```

Comment: do you want to update the table or just return those values

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to copy each name on the "next" row.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with a self join and window functions:

```
update mytable t
inner join (
    select id, lag(name) over(order by id) as lag_name
    from mytable
) t1 on t1.id = t.id
set t.name = t1.lag_name
where t1.lag_name is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated query as follows:

```
Update your_table t
   Set t.name = 
       Coalesce(Select ttt.name from your_table ttt 
                 where ttt.id = (Select max(tt.id) from your_table tt
                                 Where tt.id < t.id))
              , t.name)
```